# Measuration By Division

Tags: c++, c, function, math

The function is `y=x^2+2x+1` and the domain is from 0 to 10. If you enter the number of intervals, your program prints the result. Complete the function, `MeasurationByDivision()`.

I made below C code, but I'v got really wrong result.. 
I think I'm missing something wrong..

It should be this result:

```
10  
505.000000  
35  
460.612245
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void MeasurationByDivision( double* result, int intervals );
float f(float t) { return( pow(t,3) + 2 ); } 

int main(void) { 
    int intervals ;
    double result=0;
    scanf("%d", &intervals ) ;
    MeasurationByDivision(&result, intervals ) ;
    printf( "%lf\n", result ) ; 

    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}

void MeasurationByDivision(double* result, int intervals)
{


    int i,a=0;
    double x = 10/(double)intervals;
    float y[100];

for(i=1; i<=intervals; i++) {

    y[i]=a+i*x;
    *result += x*f(y[i]);

} 
}
```

This code result is:

```
10   
3045.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

> The function is `y=x^2+2x+1`

So why is your function this?

```
float f(float t) { return( pow(t,3) + 2 ); }
```

Change it to match the given function, and you should get the expected results.

I'd also get rid of the 100-element array: you don't need an array at all, and things will go horribly wrong if you try more than 100 intervals.

Comment: thank u... I should get rid of the 100 array quickly..xD.. I just edited the code to float f(float t) { return((t + 1)*(t + 1) ); BUT I get not expected result : not 35 460.612245 but 35 460.612239... It should be 460.612245.. why did I get this result?

Comment: That's because `float` can't represent all numbers accurately. You get the closest value that can be represented.

Answer (score 2):

```
float f(float t) { return( pow(t,3) + 2 ); }
```

to

```
float f(float t) { return((t + 1)*(t + 1) ); }
```

ADD to **It should be 460.612245.. why did I get this result?**

use

```
double f(double t) { return((t + 1)*(t + 1) ); } 
...
double y[100];
```

Comment: aww thank u! I edit the code to float f(float t) { return((t + 1)*(t + 1) ); BUT I get not expected result : not 35
460.612245 but 35 460.612239... It should be 460.612245.. why did I get this result?

Comment: @anna I think it's probably because the accuracy of the float is not enough.

Comment: yes I changed the float to double, and i have the result expected. thank u! :)